# `kernel.core_pattern` is not effective on my Ubuntu 18.04 VM after rebooting

Tags: 18.04, kernel, configuration, systemd-coredump

### Test Environment

I'm using the [`ubuntu/bionic64` Vagrant box](https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/bionic64) as my test environment.

### Pre-conditions

After creating the VM, I only installed `ansible 2.9.23` by following [the instructions in the official document](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible-on-ubuntu).

I also installed the `ansible.posix` collection (`ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.posix`) because I'll want to use the module `ansible.posix.sysctl`.

Verify the current core pattern was not what I wanted:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ sysctl kernel.core_pattern
kernel.core_pattern = |/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E
```

Also, `/etc/sysctl.conf` didn't have the core pattern:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ grep "core_pattern" /etc/sysctl.conf
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$
```

### My Intention

I want to change the core pattern to `/var/tmp/core.%h.%e.%t`.

### What I Did

I ran the following `ansible` command:

```
ansible -bKvvv -m "sysctl" -a "name=kernel.core_pattern state=present value='/var/tmp/core.%h.%e.%t' reload=yes" localhost
```

and it succeeded with the output:

```
localhost | CHANGED => {
    "changed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "ignoreerrors": false, 
            "name": "kernel.core_pattern", 
            "reload": true, 
            "state": "present", 
            "sysctl_file": "/etc/sysctl.conf", 
            "sysctl_set": false, 
            "value": "/var/tmp/core.%h.%e.%t"
        }
    }
}
```

I also checked the current configuration:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:/etc$ sysctl kernel.core_pattern
kernel.core_pattern = /var/tmp/core.%h.%e.%t
```

I also confirmed that the `core_pattern` was written into `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ grep "core_pattern" /etc/sysctl.conf 
kernel.core_pattern=/var/tmp/core.%h.%e.%t
```

Then I rebooted my VM. After rebooting, the currently effective `core_pattern` got rolled back:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ sysctl kernel.core_pattern
kernel.core_pattern = |/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E
```

### My Thoughts and What I Have Tried

[This question](https://serverfault.com/q/270201/125167) doesn't seem to be applicable for me because, firstly, it was asked about 10 years ago and, secondly, Ubuntu Server 18.04 does not seem to use `upstart` anymore.

I thought some other `.conf` files may be read later than `/etc/sysctl.conf` so the settings were overridden somewhere. But [`sysctl(8)` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/sysctl.8.html) lists the order of the `.conf` files to be read and it looks like `/etc/sysctl.conf` should be the last one that overrides everything else.

[`sysctl.conf(5)` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/sysctl.conf.5.html) provides the list of the same order as `sysctl(8)`.

I didn't find anything in [`sysctl.d(5)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/sysctl.d.5.html), either. In fact, its section "CONFIGURATION DIRECTORIES AND PRECEDENCE" confirms my understanding:

> Files in /etc/ override files with the same name in /run/ and /lib/. Files in /run/ override files with the same name in /lib/.

I found `kernel.core_pattern` would be set as expected once I ran `sudo sysctl --system` manually. That may mean that by default these system settings are not read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further investigation, I found `kernel.core_pattern` was overwritten by the [package `apport`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport) at system booting.

I should have thought of checking `apport` when I saw the string "/usr/share/apport/apport". I wasn't sure if `apport` was actually the one that overwrites `kernel.core_pattern`, so I decided to take a look at its source code.

By running `apt-cache policy apport`, I found the version I was using was `2.20.9-0ubuntu7.24`:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ apt-cache policy apport
apport:
  Installed: 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.24
  Candidate: 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.24
  Version table:
 *** 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.24 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.20.9-0ubuntu7 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$
```

Then on `apport`'s [LaunchPad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/apport), I found its download link: [apport_2.20.9-0ubuntu7.tar.gz](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/apport/2.20.9-0ubuntu7/apport_2.20.9-0ubuntu7.tar.gz).

Searching in the source code, I found the file `debian/apport.init` has the following content:

```
do_start()
{
    ...
    ...
    echo "|$AGENT %p %s %c %d %P" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
    echo 2 > /proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable
}
```

So I ran `dpkg -L apport` on my VM to see if there was this file:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ dpkg -L apport | grep init
/etc/init.d
/etc/init.d/apport
```

There wasn't any file with the exactly matching file name, but I decided to take a look at `/etc/init.d/apport` and found this was the file I was looking for:

```
do_start()
{
        ...
        ...
        echo "|$AGENT %p %s %c %d %P %E" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
        echo 2 > /proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable
}
```

I knew that `/etc/sysctl.conf` is read by the service `systemd-sysctl`, so the next thing I wanted to determine was whether `systemd-sysctl` was started before `apport`.

I searched if there was any `apport`-related service and found one:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ systemctl list-units | grep apport
apport.service                                                                      loaded active exited    LSB: automatic crash report generation
```

I then checked their inter-dependency and found `apport.service` is started after `systemd-sysctl.service`:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ systemctl list-dependencies apport.service
apport.service
● ├─system.slice
● └─sysinit.target
...
●   ├─systemd-sysctl.service
...
...
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$
```

That means `systemd-sysctl.service` correctly reads my setting of `kernel.core_pattern` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` but the setting is then immediately overwritten by `apport.service`.

To verify this, I added two lines in `/etc/init.d/apport`:

```
do_start()
{
        ...
        ...
        # NOTE(ywen): Write the current value to a file.
        sysctl kernel.core_pattern > /home/vagrant/sysctl.kernel.core_pattern.txt

        echo "|$AGENT %p %s %c %d %P %E" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
        echo 2 > /proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable

        # NOTE(ywen): Append the current value to the file.
        sysctl kernel.core_pattern >> /home/vagrant/sysctl.kernel.core_pattern.txt
}
```

Then I rebooted the VM. When the VM was up again, I found the file `/home/vagrant/sysctl.kernel.core_pattern.txt` had the following content:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ cat sysctl.kernel.core_pattern.txt 
kernel.core_pattern = /var/tmp/core.%h.%e.%t
kernel.core_pattern = |/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$
```

So, indeed, my setting was correctly read but then overwritten by `apport`.